# Laplacian - Gradient equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, laplacian

Supossedly the laplacian operator as a matrix has the following equivalence:

\begin{equation}
L = G^{T}G
\end{equation}

But Im not being able to demonstrate this. The most similar thing I did is:

\begin{equation}
L = Gx^{T}Gx+Gy^{T}Gy
\end{equation}

Where $L, Gx, Gy$ are as follows. All of them for a 4x4 matrix
\begin{equation}
L 
=    
\begin{smallmatrix}
    2.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\-1.0 & 3.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & -1.0 & 3.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 2.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\-1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 3.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 4.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 4.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 3.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 3.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 4.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 4.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 3.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 2.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 3.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 3.0 & -1.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 2.0
\end{smallmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
Gx
=    
\begin{smallmatrix}
-1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & -1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 1.0
\end{smallmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
Gy
=    
\begin{smallmatrix}
1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0 & 0.0 \\0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -1.0
\end{smallmatrix}
\end{equation}

Could you help me to figured out how matrix G should be to fulfill the first equivalence?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Find the SVD of $$L=UDV^T$$ 
Since $L$ is symmetric, the decomposition reduces to $$L=VDV^T$$
From this you can obtain the desired matrix as $$G=D^{1/2}\,V^T$$ 
Normally, you'd use a Cholesky Decomposition to find $G$, but in this case $L$ is rank-deficient.